# How to cache error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on JavaScript Web Socket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm working on JavaScript client websocket. Code work fine once I run both server program and my below client javascript.

```
   try {
        webSocket = new WebSocket(webSocketURL);
        webSocket.onopen = function(openEvent) {
            console.log("WebSocket OPEN: " + JSON.stringify(openEvent, null, 4));
        };
        webSocket.onclose = function (closeEvent) {
            console.log("WebSocket CLOSE: " + JSON.stringify(closeEvent, null, 4));
        };
        webSocket.onerror = function (errorEvent) {
            console.log("WebSocket ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(errorEvent, null, 4));
        };
        webSocket.onmessage = function (messageEvent) {
            var wsMsg = messageEvent.data;
            console.log("WebSocket MESSAGE: " + wsMsg);
            if (wsMsg.indexOf("error") > 0) {
                console.log (wsMsg.error); 
            } else {
                console.log (wsMsg); 
            }
        };
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
    }
```

But, I got an error '`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`' that cached by webbrowser. But my code can not catch this error.

Regarding see error message from this picture https://ibb.co/bHSBw0G. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the server isn't running. Are you sure you have a websocket server listening on port 8088?

Comment: Dear Elan Hamburger , Yes I stop the server to check whether client is able to capture error or not.

Comment: So is your question how to catch the connection refused error?

Comment: Dear Elan Hamburger. Yes and sorry about that, I already edited my question.

Comment: did you use http or https? pleas check about that carefully

Comment: What's wrong with using the `onerror` method to catch and handle the error?

Comment: Dear  Elan Hamburger, error was fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think ErrorEvent has non enumerable properties (only enumerable being isTrusted getter - not super useful). Try accessing property explicitly by doing something like:

```js
webSocket.onerror = function (errorEvent) {
  console.log("WebSocket ERROR: " + errorEvent.message)
}
```